# Fresh SP2010 Install > Should I install Hotfixes or SP1

Tags: installation

Just finished installing SP2010. Is it good practice to install hot-fixes or sp1 before stating with the full configuration?

Is there an order I should deploy these hotfixes or sp? If yes, what all I should install and the order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically my team doesn't just install the "latest" CU, but the latest one we are comfortable is stable.  Currently we are going to August CU.  We install all system patches, SP1 and the CU update before configuring the farm.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest running Windows Update with the additional recommendations for Office enabled. This will get your updates installed and happy. If you're doing it manually, download SP1, then the latest CU, which I think is December

Answer (score 1):

Always install the latest service pack but the CU is optional.  Officially, Microsoft only recommends installing the CU if it contains a fix for an issue you are seeing.

Unofficially, whenever I build a new farm I always install the latest CU and haven't gotten bit yet.

Comment: Except if you want UPS to work, then you need at least the June CU as well as SP1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget CU for SQL Server, they are sometimes appreciate.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a comment instead of an answer? Let me know and I can convert it for you...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what has already been said, you can slipstream the contents of CU's and/or service packs into the install itself.

Answer (score 0):

Installing updates that only apply to a certain bug that fixes your environment sets a farm to multiple issues. As a PFE, I recommend picking a strategy of applying either current CU (N) or N-1 or N-2 at the most. Keeping a patched environment saves unneeded troubleshooting and a generally healthier platform. If you are concerned about a CU, test in a lower life cycle before deploying. Installing SP and then CU is a typical scenario.

Comment: I believe our answers and strategies are based on similar ideas.  I guess the part that I would challenge is targeting CU (N) initially if it is very fresh with little community feedback.  As a PFE you may have access to additional information, but you have to admit that some CUs have been more stable than others.  In addition, how quickly can or should an existing environment deploy a CU?  The planning often takes 2 months in many of the environments I work in and by then another CU is available.

Answer (score 0):

I'm deploying the August 2011 CU on nearly every deployment at the moment. There are some issues surrounding Audience compilation it seems there are some fixes in the Dec 2011 CU and we will be tested that soon.